# Can all of Facebook's data be wiped out?

Tags: facebook, availability, datacenter

Is there a possibility that Facebook's entire data could ever be wiped out by a team of malicious individuals or even a government? Remotely or physically.

If so, how do you think they would go about doing it and what sort of safeguards does Facebook have to address both a remote attack or a physical attack on its data centers ?

Comment: A good answer to this question would need to outline Facebook's approach to physical storage of their data (surely not a simple task and probably requires some degree of speculation), then address how to go about attacking that data storage from a variety of threat models (outside network attacker, physical infiltration, insider threat, nation state, etc.). I think this question is too broad, and needs to narrow down its assumptions about an organization's data storage (i.e., not necessarily Facebook but some organization whose storage looks like X) and narrow its threat model.

Answer (score 0):

I want to highlight some points in response to your question and according to my best knowledge. Anyhow to give a more appropriate answer, need your question more specific.

In both cases

**1)** The risk factor remains everywhere. Even if something has 0.1 percent chance of bad happening, it might happen... “Risk theory”

**2)** Facebook is a huge company with large research and development sector. Surely, they have appropriate arrangement of data loss recoveries and to prevent hackers to wipe out their data.

**3)** Every process take some time so if such kind of activity starts happening, their immune system will detect the anomalies and take appropriate actions before a huge loss happens.

**4)** Even scrapping Facebook public data for research purpose requires proper legal permissions. They have checks for such activities.